# Use TQDM Progress Bar with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

Is it possible to use TQDM progress bar when importing and indexing large datasets using Pandas?

Here is an example of of some 5-minute data I am importing, indexing, and using to_datetime.  It takes a while and it would be nice to see a progress bar.

```
#Import csv files into a Pandas dataframes and convert to Pandas datetime and set to index

eurusd_ask = pd.read_csv('EURUSD_Candlestick_5_m_ASK_01.01.2012-05.08.2017.csv')
eurusd_ask.index = pd.to_datetime(eurusd_ask.pop('Gmt time'))
```

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Answer (score 239):

Find length by getting shape

```
for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0]):
   print("index",index)
   print("row",row)
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution than from @sonance207, as this does not convert the iterator to a list, but accesses a given property.

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work with df.itertuples() ?

Comment: no, but he is asking while reading...if you have a dataframe already are you assuming the file has been read once?

Comment: doesn't iterrows slow down processing by a lot?

Comment: Basically, the example shows that you can use `df.shape[0]` to get a length of the list. Otherwise, you can replace `df.iterrows()` any other compatible method.

Comment: @Giacomo: At least for me and tqdm version '4.42.0' it also works for itertuples. `for idx_row, col1, col2, ... in tqdm.tqdm(df.itertuples(), total=len(df)):`

Comment: holds also for tqdm_notebook

Answer (score 23):

```
with tqdm(total=Df.shape[0]) as pbar:    
    for index, row in Df.iterrows():
        pbar.update(1)
        ...
```

Comment: the `with` statement does close the object for you

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for tqdm > 4.24.
As per https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#pandas-integration:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
        
# Register `pandas.progress_apply` and `pandas.Series.map_apply` with `tqdm`
# (can use `tqdm_gui`, `tqdm_notebook`, optional kwargs, etc.)
tqdm.pandas(desc="my bar!")
eurusd_ask['t_stamp'] = eurusd_ask['Gmt time'].progress_apply(pd.Timestamp)
eurusd_ask.set_index(['t_stamp'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fill a pandas data frame in line by line by reading the file normally and simply add each new line as a new row to the dataframe, though this would be a fair bit slower than just using Pandas own reading methods.

Answer (score 1):

I find it very easy to implement. You only need to add the total argument.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(PATH_TO_FILE)


for index, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(),  total=df.shape[0], desc=f'Reading DF'):
        print(row(['df_colum'])
```